# SQL - join two tables based on up-to-date entries

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables

1- Table of TestModules

TestModules

[image]

2- Table of TestModule_Results

TestModule_Results

[image]

in order to get the required information for each TestModule, I am using FULL OUTER JOIN and it works fine.

FULL OUTER JOIN result

[image]

But what is required is slightly different. The above picture shows that TestModuleID = 5 is listed twice, and the requirement is to list the 'up-to-date' results based on time 'ChangedAt'

Of course, I can do the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TestModule_Results
WHERE DeviceID = 'xxx' and TestModuleID = 'yyy'
ORDER BY ChangedAt DESC
```

But this solution is for a single row and I want to do it in a Stored Procedure.

Expected output should be like:
[ExpectedOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baEiP.png)

Any advise how can I implement it in a SP?

Comment: Edit your question as copy paste your actual data. and let us know the expected output.

Comment: Better to replace image with your text formatted data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Common Table Expression and Row_Number to add a field identifying the newest results, if any, and select for just those

```
--NOTE: a Common Table Expression requires the previous command
--to be explicitly terminiated, prepending a ; covers that
;WITH cteTR as (
    SELECT * 
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DeviceID, TestModuleID 
            ORDER BY ChangedAt DESC) AS ResultOrder
    FROM TestModule_Results
    --cteTR is now just like TestModule_Results but has an 
    --additional field ResultOrder that is 1 for the newest, 
    --2 for the second newest, etc. for every unique (DeviceID,TestModuleID) pair
)
SELECT * 
FROM TestModules as M  --Use INNER JOIN to get only modules with results, 
  --or LEFT OUTER JOIN to include modules without any results yet
  INNER JOIN cteTR as R
    ON M.DeviceID = R.DeviceID AND M.TestModuleID = R.TestModuleID
WHERE R.ResultOrder = 1 
-- OR R.ResultOrder IS NULL --add if Left Outer Join
```

Comment: by using 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' to include modules without any result yet --> I still get only modules with result....I think it is because 'R.ResultOrder = 1'. I have to add a new column 'ResultOrder'  in Table: TestModules with a fixed value of 1

Comment: Sorry, you also need OR ResultOrder IS NULL to get the modules without results, I fixed my answer to reflect this. You shouldn't need to add anything to TestModules if you add this OR condition

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as such so future users can distinguish working solutions from duds. Remember, in Stack Overflow, *YOU* are the quality control department!

Comment: There is one downside that may affect the performance of the SP. The part of script ....';WITH cteTR'  ... will take relatively long time if the size of Table 'TestModule_Results' are greater than 10000 rows.

Comment: Whole books could be written on that subject, and I'm not qualified to write them, but in general a CTE solution performs comparably to a nested table solution. https://www.sqlshack.com/why-is-my-cte-so-slow/ You may also find that it performs poorly as an ad-hoc query but does better when you put it in a stored procedure or a SSRS report because of caching. But I have no silver bullet, for my own queries I look at the data and try to filter down result set sizes as early in the process as possible. You have a working query, save a copy and tinker with variants for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You say "this solution is for a single row"? Excellent. Use `CROSS APPLY` and change the  `WHERE` clause from hand-input literal to the fields of the original table. `APPLY` operates at row level.

```
SELECT *
FROM TestModules t
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TestModule_Results
    WHERE TestModule_Results.DeviceID = TestModules.DeviceID -- put the connecting fields here
    ORDER BY ChangedAt DESC
)tr
```

Comment: It looks a nice solution, but I am struggling to solve an error message <br/> the multi-part identifier '#temp_table13.DeviceID' could not be bound <br/> <pre> SELECT *
 FROM #temp_table13 t
 CROSS APPLY
 (
  SELECT TOP 1 * FROM T_TestModule_Results
  WHERE #temp_table13.DeviceID = T_TestModule_Results.DeviceID AND T_TestModule_Results.TestModuleID=  #temp_table13.TestModuleID
  ORDER BY ChangedAt DESC
 )tr<code>

Comment: In that case, can you please mention you full-join code in your question, so I may re-create the solution accordingly?